# add custom field in the billing and shipping address in magento and also show its data in backend

Tags: php, magento

I have tried all solutions but neither of any work

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/

https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/how-to-add-custom-field-in-the-billing-and-shipping-address-of-onepage-checkout-in-magento/

Can anyone help me with better solution.

in this if field is shown in frontend in billing address but not in shiping address and also i can't see its data in admin end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you followed [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/08/20/checkout-add-extra-address-field/) tutorial, and it the latest/update to [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/29/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address/)

I would guess you did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name='checkout.onepage.billing'>
            <block type='checkout/onepage_billing' name='form.additional.info' template='address/checkout/onepage/billing_field.phtml'></block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

And that simply adds the field to the billing address form, not the shipping inclusive.

To make it appear on both forms, what you want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name='checkout.onepage.billing'>
            <block type='checkout/onepage_billing' name='form.additional.info' template='address/checkout/onepage/billing_field.phtml'></block>
        </reference>
        <reference name='checkout.onepage.shipping'>
            <block type='checkout/onepage_shipping' name='form.additional.info' template='address/checkout/onepage/shipping_field.phtml'></block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

and create phtml file name billing_field.phtml and shipping_field.phtml in the right directory path.

Now we need to store this data in your database tables. The field will be stored in `sales_flat_quote_address` and `sales_flat_order_address` tables. We need to add the respective columns through setup files.

You need to create an upgrade of your install file and add this to it:

```
/**
 * Adding Extra Column to sales_flat_quote_address
 * to store the delivery instruction field
 */
$sales_quote_address = $installer->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($sales_quote_address, 'table_name', array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Table Comment'
    ));

/**
 * Adding Extra Column to sales_flat_order_address
 * to store the delivery instruction field
 */
$sales_order_address = $installer->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($sales_order_address, 'table_name', array(
        'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'comment' => 'Table Comment'
    ));
```

This will add extra column to the database tables. But we need to do another important thing, which need tell magento to copy the field from quote address object to order address object. Add these lines to your config.xml file:

```
<global>
   <fieldsets>
       <sales_convert_quote_address>
           <table_name>
               <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
           </table_name>
       </sales_convert_quote_address>
   </fieldsets>
</global>
```

In the end we need to show the new field , where address is displayed.
Magento use address templates to display address information everywhere, so we just need to add this field to the address templates. Address templates are located in System Configuration -> Customer Configuration

We will add this code to the upgrade script earlier created:

```
$config = Mage::getModel('core/config');

//append delivery instruction to address templates in system configuration
$html = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/html');
$html .= '{{depend table_name}}<br/>DH:{{var table_name}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/html', $html);

$text = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/text');
$text .= '{{depend table_name}}DT:{{var table_name}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/text', $text);

$oneline = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/oneline');
$oneline .= '{{depend table_name}}DO:{{var table_name}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/oneline', $oneline);

$pdf = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/pdf');
$pdf .= '{{depend table_name}}<br/>DP:{{var table_name}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/pdf', $pdf);

$js_template = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/customer/address_templates/js_template');
$js_template .= '{{depend table_name}}<br/>DJ:{{var table_name}} {{/depend}}';
$config->saveConfig('customer/address_templates/js_template', $js_template);
```

**Now clear your installation CACHE and run your application**

**Note: you can clear your cache here: installation > var > cache**